# Number of YouTube search results not showing

Tags: youtube, search

When I search on YouTube and press enter the number of results not showing!!! Why??
I want to show results like this picture

[image]

Comment: It would have been preferable if you had edited your other question with this information.  This question is a little better, but it's still hard to tell what the screen you are getting looks like and where the image came from (it could be an older screencap, for example, and not representative of the current UI).

Comment: What is the hard of this question ..I really don't know.It is very clear!!

Answer (score 0):

this future is no longer supported by YouTube

[image]

but you can get your "About results" by searching this in Google:

> **`stuart draper site:https://www.youtube.com/`**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try in Google or Google Videos with:

allintitle:”text_to_search” site:www.youtube.com